# What's the underlying storage engine in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, time-series, iotdb, apache-iotdb

Does the underlying storage engine in Apache IoTDB use other mature storage engine, like RocksDB, LevelDB or Cassandra? Or it implements its own storage engine from sratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache IoTDB does not rely on any existing storage engine indeed. In fact, it has its own implementation for the datastore based on a newly developed file format `tsfile` (which is related to Apache Parquet). More information on the `tsfile` Format can be found here: http://iotdb.apache.org/SystemDesign/TsFile/Format.html

Also for metadata storage, Apache IoTDB relies on its own implementation of the known algorithms / concepts like BTrees, the write ahead log (WAL) or the Raft protocol (in Cluster mode).

In the following picture you see a sketch of the storage engine / architecture of Apache IoTDB taken from http://iotdb.apache.org/SystemDesign/StorageEngine/StorageEngine.html:

[image]

TL;DR:
Apache IoTDB does not rely on existing projects but implements everything related to its storage engine completely new based on a binary file format for mass data storage.

Answer (score 1):

We build Apache IoTDB from scratch :)

The data file is called TsFile (Time series File), which is optimized for time series data query.

IoTDB engine is built based on TsFile.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).